# Как построить графикиз Excel файла с 3 столбцами?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, matplotlib, plotly

Есть Excel файл с 3 столбцами, с данными вида :

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Kак построить графики, чтобы по одной оси были данные по датам, по другой шкале 2 графика в сравнении?

Пробовал вот такой вариант :

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

table = pd.read_excel('c/.../plot_rus.xls')
x = table.values[:, 0]
y = table.values[:, 1]

plt.figure(figsize=(15, 7))
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
```

Но тут строит только `data` и `data1`.

Comment: у вас должно быть два plt.plot:один должен строить график так, чтобы x - была колонка с датой, а y - c данными из data1, второй, соответственно, чтобы x - была опять колонка с датой, а y - с data2.

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте так:

```
df = pd.read_excel('c/.../plot_rus.xls')
df['data'] = pd.to_datetime(df['data'], errors="coerce")
df.set_index("data").plot()
```